# mysql select an average from order by with a query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables "recipes", "recipes_items" , in the table recipes_items i have an  integer columns "important". Now I have a query that pulls the recipes ordered by the sum(important) of the `recipes_items.important` , the order by  have a sub query :

```
(SELECT sum(...) from recipes_items...) DESC)
```

BUT what I want is to retrieve as additional column in the recipes query the average of the column "important" from table recipes_items
How can that be ?

Thanks
Moshe

```
select  recipes.recipeName,
        recipes.recipeID,
        AVG (recipes_items.importance) AS averageScore
    from  recipes,recipes_items
    WHERE  recipes_items.recipeID=recipes.recipeID
    ORDER BY  
      ( SELECT  SUM(recipes_items.importance) AS sumImportance
            FROM  recipes_items
            WHERE  recipes_items.recipeID = recipes.recipeID
              AND  recipes_items.itemID IN ('1059')
      ) DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

What i would like to get in results is order by the importance column from recipes_items.itemID that are matching a set of ID's in the 'IN()' section, also wanted to have the number or sum of the matching ID's in each row of a matching ID's to the `recipes_items.itemID`...

Comment: Provide sample records and expected answer please

Comment: You want average of "recipes_items.important" as another column?

Comment: yes, exactly but keep the order by query the same

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your full query but you can likely do this without a subquery and still include the average:

```
SELECT recipes.id, recipes.name, AVG(recipes_items.important)
FROM recipes
LEFT JOIN recipes_items ON (recipes.id = recipes_items.recipe_id)
GROUP BY recipes.id
ORDER BY SUM(recipes_items.important) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you @Jim the full query is :
select recipes.recipeName, recipes.recipeID ,AVG (recipes_items.importance) AS averageScore
from recipes,recipes_items  
WHERE recipes_items.recipeID=recipes.recipeID
ORDER BY 
 (SELECT SUM(recipes_items.importance) AS sumImportance FROM recipes_items WHERE `recipes_items`.`recipeID` = `recipes`.`recipeID` AND  `recipes_items`.`itemID` IN ('1059')) DESC LIMIT 20

Comment: What i would like to get in results is order by the importance column from recipes_items.itemID that are matching a set of ID's in the 'IN()' section, also wanted to have the number or sum of the matching ID's in each row of a matching ID's to the `recipes_items.itemID`..